# How to write a LINQ Query with two join statements in LINQ method syntax?

Tags: c#, linq

I have written the following code in query syntax and it works fine. All properties in the following code are boolean properties in my model class and has 0 or 1 value.

```
var isTrue = (from x in _context.Fruit
              join y in _context.Taste on x.Id equals y.Id
      join z in color on x.Id equals z.JobId
              where (x.Id == y.Id)
              select x.prop1 && x. prop2 && x. prop3
              && y. prop4 && y. prop5 && y. prop6 && y. prop7
              && y. prop8 && y. prop8 && y. prop9
              && y. prop9 && y. prop10 && y. prop11
              && y. prop12 && y. prop13 && y. prop14
      && z.prop13 && z.prop14).FirstOrDefault();
```

But i need to write this linq query using method syntax.
Any hint please..

Comment: Why do you "need" to write it using method syntax?

Comment: A hint? JustDecompile or dotPeek.

Comment: http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work/ should help you - but personally I'd stick with the query expression syntax. (I'd get rid of the space after each "." though...)

Comment: Your Join'll like _contex.Fruit.Join(_context.Taste,fruit=>fruit.Id,taste=>taste.Id), other methods don't look like pain. Looks like a homework, thought. Also, what is "z"?

Comment: maybe I am missing something, but what is z?

Comment: Why do you need the Where, the fact that x.Id == y.Id should already be ensured by the join, isn't it?

Comment: It is type mistake... z is actually y. i have updated my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that, you need to use the `Join`-LINQ-Method twice to build two tuples, where the final tuple is created from the first tuple. The first tuple contains the element pairs of `Fruit` and `Taste`. So let us call it `fruitTasteTuple`. The second `Join` will create another tuple containing pairs of the two tuple elements of the first tuple (the `fruitTasteTuple`), which was created before, and an element of `color`. This tuple i've called `fruitTasteColorTuple`.

To make this easier to understand: In the second `Join` I'm creating tuple pairs of the first tuple enumeration and the color enumeration. For better usage I've unwrapped the first tuple into the second tuple.

The method chain version should be:

```
_context.Fruit.Join(_context.Taste, x => x.Id, y => y.Id, (x, y) => new { x, y })
              .Join(color, fruitTasteTuple => fruitTasteTuple.x.Id, z => z.JobId, (fruitTasteTuple, z) => new { fruitTasteTuple.x, fruitTasteTuple.y, z })
              .Select(fruitTasteColorTuple =>
                    fruitTasteColorTuple.x.prop1 &&
                    fruitTasteColorTuple.x.prop2 &&
                    fruitTasteColorTuple.x.prop3 &&
                    fruitTasteColorTuple.y.prop4 &&
                    fruitTasteColorTuple.y.prop5 &&
                    fruitTasteColorTuple.y.prop6 &&
                    fruitTasteColorTuple.y.prop7 &&
                    fruitTasteColorTuple.y.prop8 &&
                    fruitTasteColorTuple.y.prop8 &&
                    fruitTasteColorTuple.y.prop9 &&
                    fruitTasteColorTuple.y.prop9 &&
                    fruitTasteColorTuple.y.prop10 &&
                    fruitTasteColorTuple.y.prop11 &&
                    fruitTasteColorTuple.y.prop12 &&
                    fruitTasteColorTuple.y.prop13 &&
                    fruitTasteColorTuple.y.prop14 &&
                    fruitTasteColorTuple.z.prop13 &&
                    fruitTasteColorTuple.z.prop14)
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

The `Where` doesn't occur here, because its purpose should be handled by the `Join` method.

Comment: What if i have 3rd table as well e.g. color.. How i will create join on three tables using method syntax?

Comment: I've adjusted may answer according your changes to the question.

Comment: I am getting exception "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Sequence contains more than one element"

Comment: I think i need to put where clause to identify only single row from the table. right?

Comment: Since `x.Id` and `y.Id` were used to build the tuples, the `Where` clause to check thier equality is redundant. If you want to filter the tuples by a value, you need to add it again. For example if you want to  filter for a specific ID: `.Where(fruitTasteColorTuple => fruitTasteColorTuple.x.Id == idFromMethodParameter)`

Comment: the results are incorrect if i tasted has more than one matching row. i mean fruite and Taste has 1-M relationship. Well above query ignore 2nd row from taste table.

Comment: I have no idea what your data looks like. But I think it doesn't belong to this question. If you have got another problem, open another question. Your next problem sounds to me as if you should take a look at the `GroupBy` method.

Comment: I have opened another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314332/linq-to-check-boolean-result-in-table-and-return-true-or-false-3-tables-join

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in writing it that way or the other way round. The compiler compiles it always in a method expression (called lambda) like follows:

```
_context.Fruit.Join(_context.Taste, i => i.Id, i => i.Id,
                    (fruit,taste) => new { Condition = fruit.prop1 && ... })
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

As requested in the comment section the join for a 3rd table can be written as follows

```
_context.Fruit.Join(_context.Taste, i => i.Id, i => i.Id,
                    (fruit,taste) => new { Taste = taste, Fruit = fruit })
              .Join(_context.Color, i => i.Id, i => i.Fruit.ColorId,
                    (f, color) => new { f.Taste, f.Fruit, Color = color})
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: What if i have 3rd table as well e.g. color.. How i will create join on three tables using method syntax?

Comment: I have modified my answer to provide you the join for a third table

Answer (score 0):

In your query you can't use z(which is undefined), but (with the power of Resharper) you can do something like this:

```
var isTrue = (_context.Fruit.Join(_context.Taste, x => x.Id, y => y.Id, (x, y) => new {x, y})
                        .Where(t => (t.x.Id == t.y.Id))
                        .Select(
                          t =>
                          t.x.prop1 && t.x.prop2 && t.x.prop3 && t.y.prop4 && t.y.prop5 && t.y.prop6 && t.y.prop7 &&
                          t.y.prop8 && t.y.prop8 && t.y.prop9 && t.y.prop9 && t.y.prop10 && t.y.prop11)).FirstOrDefault();
```