# Linq to check boolean result in table and return true or false (3 tables join)

Tags: linq

i have 3 tables A,b,C

Table A has 1-M relationship with table B and 1-1 relationship with table C.

**"Table A"** has three boolean properties a1Completed, a2Completed, a3Completed.

**"Table B"** has also three boolean Properties b1Completed, b2Completed, b3Completed.

**"Table C"** has 2 boolean properties c1.Completed and C2Completed.

I want to write LINQ query to return either true or false after checking all the boolean properties in these 3 tables.
If all boolean properties (in all table) are true then return true else false. Table A & C will always has one record but table B could have more than 1 record.

I have written query as following.

```
var isTrue =    (From  a in db.A
    .join b in db.B on a.id equals b.jId
    .join c in db.C on a.id equals c.jId
    where (a.Id == '12345')
    select a.a1Completed 
    && a.a2Completed
    && a.a3Completed
    && b.b1Completed
    && b.b2Completed
    && b.b3Completed
    && c.C1Completed
    && c.C2Completed
    && c.C3Completed).Any();
```

This query works fine when Table B has only one record (also Table A and C has one record each).
It does not work when Tablw B has more than one record.

Any hint please?

Comment: Can you access the navigation properties? `a.bCollection` instead of a manual join?

Comment: I never tried that way.. How i can achieve my outcome using that way?

Comment: I was trying in a very simpler way since i am quite fresh .. Can you give hint please how i can do this in my way. (using manual join).. Where i am doing mistake?

Comment: Can someone comment to my issue?

Comment: Can you provide a [working code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) sample?